# Show Parameter Segment of URL using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, get

So I am trying to get the last part of a link and show it in a div on the HTML.
I'm using JavaScript and HTML to perform this; here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageURL = window.location.href;
    var lastURLSegment = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    document.getElementById("getLink").innerhtml = lastURLSegment;
</script>

<div id="getLink"></div>
```

And here is my link:

```
https://playmafia.000webhostapp.com/world/play/create/?id=m12345
```

However, after executing this, nothing happens or shows. And plus, this code, as far as I know, will retrieve "?id=m12345".

I am new to javascript so any help would be great in figuring this out. Also, this may need jQuery, I'm not completely sure, so I will accept answers that involve it.

Once again, how can I get the parameter of the URL (in the example, m12345) to display in the HTML under the div with id "getLink"? Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```js
    var pageURL="https://playmafia.000webhostapp.com/world/play/create/?id=m12345";
    var lastURLSegment = pageURL.substr(pageURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var value=lastURLSegment.substr(lastURLSegment.lastIndexOf("=")+1);
    document.getElementById("getLink").innerHTML = value;
```

```html
<div id="getLink"></div>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! I actually had to update the var pageURL to window.location.href, since the m12345 is a random parameter value, but I didn't specify that, and after that, your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing `document.getElementById("getLink").innerhtml` to `document.getElementById("getLink").innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need some changes in your code

```
document.getElementById("getLink").innerHTML = lastURLSegment;
```

TRY THIS ...

Comment: This retrieves the data "?id=m12345", rather than the "12345" that I preferred :)